# How to compute the updated shortest paths given a set of edge insertions efficiently?

Tags: graphs, shortest-path, dynamic-graphs, dynamic-algorithms

Let $G = (V, E)$ be a graph with edge weights $w: E \rightarrow \mathbb{R} \cup \{\infty\}$.
Let $P := \{(a_i, b_i, w_i)\}$ be a set of tuples of nodes $a_i, b_i \in V$ with shortest distance $w_i$ from $a_i$ to $b_i$.

We want to update the weights of a subset of edges $E' \subseteq E$, and then efficiently update the $w_i$ in $P$.
We assume that $E'$ is small compared to $E$, but not constant-sized.

How do we update the set $P$? Precomputations of some data structure based on the initial $G$, $w$ and $P$ are allowed. Are there some existing publications on this or similar problems?

Comment: There's a whole bunch of research on these types of problems.  You can look for surveys on _Fully Dynamic APSP_, for example.  There was a [paper in SODA 2020](https://arxiv.org/abs/2001.10801) that should give you some pointers.

Comment: Thanks, that pointer is really helpful!

Comment: If P is small or only has a few start points, you can use (multiple instances of) LPA*. See [this post](https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/questions/11855/how-do-the-state-of-the-art-pathfinding-algorithms-for-changing-graphs-d-d-l)